# How to create template function in SWIG for c++?

Tags: c++, python-2.7, swig

I have a template function with following signature in c++ file

```
template <class T> std::vector<T> function(T);
```

I wanna make an interface file to wrap main.cpp to a python file with Swig. 
How should I include Tfunction in Swig, for types int float and double?

```
//main.i
%module main
%include "carrays.i"
%array_class(double, doubleArray);

%{
   extern template <class T> std::vector<T> Tfunction(T);
%}

extern template <class T> std::vector<T> Tfunction(T);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Python does not know templates, you have to create a type for each parameter. There is a convenient %template directive you would use:

```
%template(TfunctionInt) Tfunction<int>;
```

This is explained in detail in [section 6.18 of SWIG docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn30).